# xpath only return search string

Tags: java, xpath, saxon

I want to search for the strings "formEmail", "form_q\d{1,3}" and "title" in a xml document via xpath 2.0 from saxon and want to return only list of those strings if they were found by the engine. Till know I only return a list of nodes. Is it possible to return a list of the relevant strings?

```
XPathCompiler xpath = proc.newXPathCompiler();
XPathExecutable exePath=xpath.compile(".//property[matches(@value,'formEmail|form_q\\d{1,3}$|title')]");
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the target string is in attribute named `value`, you could've returned value of matching attributes as string instead of returning the attribute's parent element, by using the following XPath :

```py
.//property/@value[matches(.,'formEmail|form_q\\d{1,3}$|title')]/string()
```

Comment: If you need to eliminate duplicate strings, then perhaps it would be better to write `distinct-values(.//property/@value [matches(.,'formEmail|form_q\\d{1,3}$|title')])`